# C# / winforms. Embedded TrackBar in StatusStrip

Tags: c#, winforms, trackbar, statusstrip

Since there was no way (that I could tell) for me to add a trackbar to a status strip using the forms designer, I have added the following code to the form load method:

```
        zoomTrackBar = new TrackBar();
        ToolStripControlHost myControlHost = new ToolStripControlHost(zoomTrackBar);
        mainStatus.Items.Add(myControlHost);
        zoomTrackBar.Minimum = 0;
        zoomTrackBar.Maximum = 100;
        myControlHost.Height = statusLabel.Height; // statusLabel is a label already in the statusstrip... I'd like to match its height but not working
```

Some things aren't working correctly. Firstly, the track bar *doesn't even appear* until I either maximize the window or resize the window repeatedly and randomly. Once it's displayed it remains there regardless of the window state.

There are already three items in the status strip before track bar added. The first item is autosized label that springs to the second and third (fixed width) labels (so the smaller fixed-width labels always stay on the right for x and y coords).

The trackbar created is gigantic. Changing the height of the control host or the trackbar itself isn't changing the trackbar height. It's making the entire status strip huge.

I'd even settle for adding a button that spawns a temporary vertical trackbar if that would be easier.

Calling Invalidate() on mainStatus does not help.

Comment: I don't know why, but the following line of code fixed everything, including the size...

    mainStatus.SetBounds(0,0,0,0);

I realize it forces a layout update, but I'm lost as to why that wasn't performed before after the form load.

Comment: Please clarify: I just added a TrackBar to a StatusStrip from the forms designer without any problem... and it seems to work perfectly... 
I use VB, but i Hope this is not the issue...

Comment: TrackBar isn't an option to add to StatusStrip from the forms designer... or maybe I'm just not seeing it.

Comment: I don't know what you have to do with it, but if you just get a TrackBar from the Toolbox and put it in a StatusStrip, it works. It is true it is not an option from StatusStrip itself, but who cares, if it suits your needs? ;)